# Delphi XE5: Problems with proper visualization of extracted GMail emails

Tags: email, delphi, encoding, gmail, gmail-api

I am facing some trouble in properly visualizing emails extracted from GMail. I use the GMail API to retrieve the messages. This part seems to be working properly and I get the json with the entire message.
Here is a small part of one of the body parts

```json
"mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
"filename": "",
"headers": [
 {
  "name": "Content-Type",
  "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=001a114710d029267205278f13b9"
 }
],
"body": {
 "size": 0
},
"parts": [
 {
  {
  "partId": "0.0",
  "mimeType": "text/plain",
  "filename": "",
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "Content-Type",
    "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
   },
   {
    "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
    "value": "quoted-printable"
   }
  ],
  "body": {
   "size": 549,
   "data": "SGkgUGF1bCwNCg0KQXBvbG9naWVzLCBidXQgSSBmb3Jnb3QgdG8gbWVudGlvbiB0aGF0IHRoZSByZXN0IG9mIHlvdXIgb3JkZXIgaGFzIGJlZW4NCnNlbnQgb3V0IGluIHRoZSBtZWFudGltZQ0KDQpNYW55IHRoYW5rcw0KDQoqS2luZCBSZWdhcmRzKg0KKkJhcmJhcmEgSm9uZXMqDQoqSW50ZXJuZXQgU2FsZXMqDQoNCipPbGQgTWlsbCBTYWRkbGVyeSoNCg0KKnd3dy5zYWRkbGVyeS5iaXogPGh0dHA6Ly93d3cuc2FkZGxlcnkuYml6Lz4qDQoNCipUZWw6ICs0NCAoMCkyOCA5MzM1IDMyNjggPCUyQjQ0JTIwJTI4MCUyOTI4JTIwOTMzNSUyMDMyNjg-Kg0KDQoqVGFrZSBhIFZpcnR1YWwgdG91ciBvZiBvdXIgc2hvcCoNCkdvb2dsZSBwbGFjZXMgaHR0cDovL2dvby5nbC85Y1o5ZDANCipbaW1hZ2U6IElubGluZSBpbWFnZXMgNF1XaXNoaW5nIHlvdSBhIHZlcnnigItbaW1hZ2U6IElubGluZSBpbWFnZXMgM10qDQoqICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgTWVycnkgQ2hyaXN0bWFzKg0KDQoq4oCLICAg4oCLICDigIsgICAgW2ltYWdlOiBJbmxpbmUgaW1hZ2VzIDJd4oCLKg0K"
  }
 }
```

So what is the data part encoded with? I am getting confused with the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" ->"quoted-printable". Should I decode the value of the data using a "quoted-printable" decoder or not?
Initially without noticing the "quoted-printable" value, I decoded the data value using DecodeBase64, here is how I am making it

```
function TViewEmailsForm.DecodeData(aStr: String): String;
var
  aStrm: TBytesStream;
  aStrStrm: TStringStream;
begin
  Result := '';
  if aStr = '' then
    Exit;

  aStrm := TBytesStream.Create(DecodeBase64(aStr));

  aStrStrm := TStringStream.Create;

  try
    aStrm.Position := 0;
    aStrStrm.LoadFromStream(aStrm);
    Result := aStrStrm.DataString;
  finally
    aStrm.Free;
    aStrStrm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Using that returns human readable text, however at the end something more is decoded and I don't get what it is. I presume it is some kind of formatting bold text, link, kind of signature but I don't succeed in anyway to show it properly (not sure what to use though as component - RichEdit, HTMLViewer)
The end of the decoded string looks like

```
.......
*Name of the company*

*website of the company <again the website of the company>*

*Tel: +44 (0)28 9335 3268 <%2B44%20%280%2928%209335%203268
ѓBѓBЉ•ZЩHHљ\ќX[Э\€Щ€Э\€ЪЬ
ѓB‘ЫЫЩЫHXЩ\И‹ЛЩЫЫЛ™ЫОXЦЋYBЉ–Ъ[XYЩN€[›[™H[XYЩ\И
UЪ\Ъ[™И[ЭHH™\ћx "ЦЪ[XYЩN€[›[™H[XYЩ\ИЧJѓBЉ€Y\њћHЪљ\ЭX\КѓBѓBЉё "И8 "И8 "ИЪ[XYЩN€[›[™H[XYЩ\И—x "КѓB›
```

I have some other messages which pretend to have html body, but again the data is seen in that way. I tried to load this string into the lines of TRichEdit, but had no luck, I tried to use TIdDecoderQuotedPrintable to decode this string, though I am not sure if I have to make it, but some of the characters got replaced by '?' (question marks)
What I am missing here and what is the proper way of visualizing the content of the messages?

Comment: If it's a signature, it could very well be a picture, e.g. a company logo.

Comment: Yes, there might be something like that there, but how to determine what it is? I guess the answer of this has something to do with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584204/changing-charset-when-retrieving-messages-from-mail-server , I was even thinking of parsing the entire json and putting it into a TIdMessage, but then what, how to visualize that mail?

Comment: FWIW, I did not find `DecodeBase64` in help of XE7 so I used `DecodeBytes64` instead, and it did return a string ending with the encoded telephone number as in your post (that is ....%203268).

Comment: What does the message look like when you read it with Chrome? Anything after the tel number?

Comment: Well I have to find out, it is not my message, nor my gmail account, I am just extracting the message to present it to the user for reference. I have to find out what the message has there, I am almost sure it is a small logo + text in bold, but have to confirm it

Comment: No, it doesn't have a logo, only several rows in bold text and some gray color of the font + two links. @TomBrunberg DecodeBase64 is from encddecd unit

Comment: Yes, now I can see the rubbish too, that is when using `DecodeBase64`. But when using `DecodeBytes64` from unit `Data.Cloud.CloudAPI` it doesn't show the rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

After serious research and testing different encoders/decoders I finally managed to properly decode what was encoded in the message.
I used Indy's `TIdEncoderMIME` found in `IdCoderMIME` and used the `DecodeString` method. The HTML messages and bodies are properly decoded too with it.
Hope this will help other people not to spend two days in "fighting" with decoding messages!

EDIT: I noticed that the symbol `>` comes as `?` Maybe there something else which has to be done?

EDIT2: It seems that the encoding of the data is not actually Base64 but Base64Url. On the following link http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi_facebook_base64_encoding.html you can find interesting post on that. The images are encoded in that way and the standard decoding doesn't work for extracting them.
Whoever knows French can read something here too http://codes-sources.commentcamarche.net/source/51156-base64-base64url-encode-decode

Comment: Thank you for letting us know. What was the content?

Comment: In fact there were images too represented only with [images inle] + some text. Finally I am using the ported from pbear HTML viewer to show the data which I take from the text/html body part, needs some tweaks yet to show the images properly, but my main problem with decoding seems to be solved